# Hibernate One-to-Many mapping by date range?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to change Train.trainFares from transient to mapped to the TrainFare class. However, I want to limit the TrainFares to those that are active for the Train.ddate. How do I do this?

I have found a Hibernate Jira [issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4284) which I believe might be the source of my problems. Has anyone else come across this issue? Did you find a workaround?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAIN")
public class Train { 

    @EmbeddedId
    private TrainPK id;

    @Column
    private String trainType;

    @Transient
    private List<TrainFare> trainFares;

    @Embeddable
    public static class TrainPK {

        @Column
        private String company;

        @Column
        private Date departDate;

        @Column 
        private String trainNumber;
    }

    ... setters & getters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEATRATE")
public class SeatRate { 

    @EmbeddedId
    private SeatRatePK id;

    @Column
    private Date expiryDate; 

    @Column
    private String trainNumber;

    @Embeddable
    public static class SeatRatePK { 

        @Column
        private String company

        @Column 
        private Date effectiveDate;

    }

    ... setters & getters
}
```

Comment: "I heard there's a bug in hibernate that will prevent me from mapping this relationship" [citation needed]

Comment: There you go Alex: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4284

Comment: Great. Thanks. I've added it to the question.